# Can not create a file using VS express 2013 while coding in C

Tags: c

I have originally used code blocks to create a program in C using structures to write to a file but I have a 64 bit computer using windows 7. Once I realized that I could not write a binary file I began my attempt to put the same program that had worked except for the garbage that was written out, into the file I copied it into VS express. After adapting change what was necessary to get a run I was not able to create a file in txt or binary. To follow is my code. Please forgive me for all of the code that was commented out but it is a work in progress.

```
int GetNewFile()
{
    struct sumCamp allrecs[50];
    char ans;
    char recName[20];

    printf("\tYou are now in the create a file.\n");
    printf("\tIf this is where you want to be enter Y in not enter N.\n");
    fflush(stdin);

    ans = getchar();

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\tThis is your answer %c \n", ans);
    if (toupper(ans) == 'Y')
    {
        puts("\tWhat is the name of the file you want to create?\n ");
        fgets(recName, 20, stdin);
        /*(gets(recName);*/
        printf("\tThis is the the file you created %s.\n", recName);
        /* clientPtr = fopen_s(recName, "w");*/
        /*errno_t errorCode = fopen_s(&clientPtr, sizeof(recName), "w+b");*/
        fopen_s(&clientPtr, (recName), "w");
    }

    if (clientPtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("\tError in creating the file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(clientPtr);

    printf("\tHello world!6\n");

    return(0);
}  

/*The structure and file also is the following;*/

FILE *clientPtr;      /*This is the file pointer*/

struct sumCamp                   /*sumCamp if the structure tag*/
{
    char name[25];
    char dateIn[6];
    char dateOut[6];
    int mealAll;                   /*These are the stucture members*/
    int mealBreak;
    int mealLunch;
    int mealDinner;
    long int contract;
    char patDate[5];
};

/*void GetInfo(void);  */         /*allrecs is the stucture varibles*/
/*struct sumCamp GetInfo (struct sumCamp allrecs[50]);*/
/* GetUpdate (void);*/
```

Comment: What's the output (console, file)? Any errors (compile-time, runtime)?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

'Change:

```
      fopen_s(&clientPtr, (recName), "w");
```

To:

```
      int rCode=fopen_s(&clientPtr, (recName), "w");
      if(rCode)
         {
         fprintf(stderr, "fopen() returned failure code: %d\n", rCode);
         exit(0);
         }
```

Then you can determine if the file is being successfully opened; and if it is not successfully opened, it will print an error code that will help to further diagnose the problem.

---

***EDIT:***

```
22   EINVAL   One of the parameters passed into 'fopen_s()' was invalid.
```

In the case of the question code, it means that 'fopen_s()' didn't like either &clientPtr or (readName).

My first guess is that something is wrong with (readName).  To verify this is the problem, you might want to (temporarily) change:

```
int rCode=fopen_s(&clientPtr, (recName), "w");
```

To something like:

```
int rCode=fopen_s(&clientPtr, "testfile.tmp", "w");
```

If rCode is '0' instead of '22', the problem is with (recName).

I am guessing that this is the case.  If so, the problem with recName is that it contains a newline *'\n'* (and perhaps a carriage return *'\r'*) character at the end.  This is fairly common when using 'fgets()' to get user input.

The *'\n'* (and *'\r'*) can be eliminated from 'recName' like by changing this:

```
...
{
    puts("\tWhat is the name of the file you want to create?\n ");
    fgets(recName, 20, stdin);
...
```

To this:

```
....
{
    char *cp;

    puts("\tWhat is the name of the file you want to create?\n ");
    fgets(recName, 20, stdin);

    for(cp=recName, *cp, ++cp)
       if(('\r' == *cp) || ('\n' == *cp))
          *cp='\0';
....
```

This should have fixed the 'recName' problem.  Now change the line back and re-test:

```
    int rCode=fopen_s(&clientPtr, (recName), "w");
```

And by the way, parenthesis are not needed around 'recname':

```
int rCode=fopen_s(&clientPtr, recName, "w");
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks,I have added as you suggested and the result error message is    fopen() returned failure code:22

Comment: @user3613841, answer is now updated with additional detail about failure code 22.